# Struggling with reading headers with pandas.read_excel

Tags: pandas, excel

I am new to Pandas and looking to leverage it for some financial analysis (I am not a data scientist). I am stuck at a very basic step: successfully reading a range of data along with its headers from a sheet in excel using pandas_read_excel.

```
Basic variables:
data_tbl_header_row = 21
data_tbl_cell1_col = 22
data_tbl_cell1_col = 2
data_tbl_celln_col = 33
data_tbl_celln_col = 7
```

Case 1: If I invoke with

```
header=None
```

:

```
df_data_tbl = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet, header=None, usecols= lambda x: x>=(data_tbl_cell1_col-1) and x <=(data_tbl_celln_col-1), skiprows= lambda x: x<(data_tbl_cell1_row-1) or x >(data_tbl_celln_row-1));
```

then I successfully obtain the data without the headers - as expected:

```
C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\scripts>C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\python.exe "Y:Try\Win\hello.py
Table Header row = 22
Table [start row, start col] = 23, 2
Table [end row, end col] = 33, 7
C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:329: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)
1 2 3 4 5 6
0 NVDA 2024-03-22 795.0 Short Put 2024-03-18
1 NVDA 2024-03-22 795.0 Short Put 2024-03-18
2 AMZN 2024-03-22 185.0 Short Call 2024-03-14
3 AMZN 2024-03-22 185.0 Short Call 2024-03-14
4 MSFT 2024-03-22 435.0 Short Call 2024-03-14
5 XLK 2024-03-22 212.5 Short Call 2024-03-14
6 BRK.B 2024-03-22 412.5 Short Call 2024-03-19
7 SMCI 2024-03-22 945.0 Short Put 2024-03-14
8 CRWD 2024-03-22 315.0 Short Put 2024-03-14
9 SMCI 2024-03-22 945.0 Short Put 2024-03-14
10 CRWD 2024-03-22 315.0 Short Put 2024-03-14
```

However if I invoke with

```
header=data_tbl_header_row-1
```

:

```
df_data_tbl = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet, header=data_tbl_header_row-1, usecols= lambda x: x>=(data_tbl_cell1_col-1) and x <=(data_tbl_celln_col-1), skiprows= lambda x: x<(data_tbl_cell1_row-1) or x >(data_tbl_celln_row-1));
```

Then I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\scripts>C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\python.exe "Y:Try\Win\hello.py
Table Header row = 22
Table [start row, start col] = 23, 2
Table [end row, end col] = 33, 7
C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:329: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 716, in _next_line
line = self._check_comments([self.data[self.pos]])[0]
~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 407, in _infer_columns
line = self._next_line()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 729, in _next_line
raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Y:\Personal\Finance Related\1 Fins\Win\hello.py", line 152, in <module>
main()
File "Y:\Personal\Finance Related\1 Fins\Win\hello.py", line 143, in main
df_data_tbl = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet, header=data_tbl_header_row-1, usecols= lambda x: x>=(data_tbl_cell1_col-1) and x <=(data_tbl_celln_col-1), skiprows= lambda x: x<(data_tbl_cell1_row-1) or x >(data_tbl_celln_row-1));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 508, in read_excel
data = io.parse(
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1616, in parse
return self._reader.parse(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 916, in parse
raise err
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 878, in parse
parser = TextParser(
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 2053, in TextParser
return TextFileReader(*args, **kwds)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1620, in __init__
self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1898, in _make_engine
return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 133, in __init__
) = self._infer_columns()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\python-3.12.2.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 417, in _infer_columns
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Passed header=[21], len of 1, but only 11 lines in file (sheet: Open Options Export)

C:\Users\wxyz\Downloads\WPy64-31220\scripts>
```

I have tried several interpretations of what header is meant to specify without any luck.  I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

I have attached screenshots of the excel file and the code.

Many thanks!

[[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SihZ8.png)][[and Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGOd3.png)]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [why we ask that you not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  Please 

[Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78189391/edit)

to include the text in-addition-to or in-place-of the image. Try to make sure your question includes a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks!